# Light Blue Monitor Screen

Tags: display

I have seen this before with an older monitor that over time, the monitor colours change to a light blue haze. This has started happening with an older monitor of mine now (A GigaByte Monitor) and although none of the pins are bent and it's a brand new machine, there is no reason, other than aging that it should show the light blue screen.

Perhaps it is just time for a new monitor, but if there is a way of saving it still. I would appreciate the insight. Perhaps there is something I have not tried, perhaps it has something to do with the new machine instead of the monitor? I had the monitor plugged into two other machines over the weekend and didn't have this problem. So I am not quite sure what to make of it.

Many thanks!

**EDIT:**
*I must also add that when I plugged the monitor into the older machines, I had [the VGA converter](http://www.tigerdirect.ca/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=244973&CatId=467) attached to the end of the newer DVI output. Which, when plugged into the newer PC, I don't need of course.*

Comment: Please try a different cable. Also, if you have another graphics port try that - since the monitor was fine on another machine it indicates either cable, GPU or the GPU port

Answer (score 5):

As @DaveRook said, the actions you have taken so far indicate that it is **not** a problem with your monitor:

- You have tried your monitor on other computers and it did not look blue -> it is not the monitor's fault

So the only other options are:

- dodgy cable
- dodgy graphics card
- odd config on your PC trying to use a colour balance which is too blue

For the first two, try swapping out the existing cable/card with a new one.

For the config, check to see if your PC has a graphics configuration setting for colour temperature or colour balance.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have added an edit to my post. I hope this helps some in the solution to the problem. Also, oddly enough, prior to plugging the cable into the older machines, I had had the monitor plugged into the new machine without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen with a laptop monitor which I'm still using now, running on Windows 7. Looking back I'm not 100% sure I can say it was ever colored right and have found out that some of the AUOs in laptops have problems all across the board.

Going back to the point, a good solution in my case was a calibrated color profile. You may do just as well buying that new monitor given an investment of at least $80 seems to be a requirement for colorimeters, and if buying new that number can reach $150 and up for the top shelf stuff. However if the color management adventure is appealing to you you can probably come out cheaper that way overall.

In my case I was lucky to find one color profile with calibration curves for my monitor model (after an exhaustive search of the internet) which happened to work quite well and which I improved upon with some serious tweaking and lots of research, though it was fun.

The fact that this other person's calibration worked for me probably supports the theory that my issue was intrinsic to the monitor, but in my hours of online color management research I have seen the statement many times that one of the main reason for profiling and calibrating a monitor is to combat the natural LCD drift that occurs and extend color-correct functioning lifespan.